# How to find the resonant frequency of a human body?

Tags: rf, analog, oscillator, resonance, biopotential

I've read that the human body has resonant frequencies somewhere around 50MHz. I also think it would be interesting to look for values in other ranges like 10-100 kHz. I'm wondering how to build a device which can measure these frequencies and track them as they change.

I was thinking about using a circuit designed for a crystal oscillator, and just putting a human where the crystal would be. However, I'm not sure about the various ways in which the analogy could fail. Also, usually circuits for crystals specify a very specific oscillation frequency. I might be looking for a circuit where, for instance, I specify a wide range like 20-40 kHz, and if I connect it to some parallel LC circuits with a resonant frequencies of 15 kHz and 34 kHz and 100 kHz, then it will oscillate at 34 kHz because that is where the impedance is minimized within the specified range.

Comment: *"and just putting a human where the crystal would be"* - you'd need some big pads to get me in there ;-)

Comment: How would you recognize a human body resonant frequency meaning, what would a human body look like in the process of resonating? Compare this with (say) a tree or a brick or a doormat - what would be the signs of resonance. If you are expecting some form of aura to develop then you are going to be disappointed.

Comment: This whole area looks like its filled with quackery - I especially like this one http://www.dhgate.com/product/new-usb-quantum-resonance-magnetic-therapy/162776797.html - a snip for around $300

Comment: There is no single answer to this and NO GOOD ANSWER in the usual sense. The body may exhibit various and varying AC impedance minima but it is a big dynamic squidgy mess of multiple varying impedances. THERE IS NO SINGLE OR SHARP resonant frequency. Anyone claiming so should be walked away from slowly. It is the sort of thing that quack 'science' is based on.

Comment: The 50 MHz figure comes from the idea that the height of an average adult (about 1.6-1.7m) is a quarter wavelength at roughly 50 MHz, so the thought is that a standing human body might act as an antenna at this frequency. But there's no real physical phenomenon to support this concept.

Comment: Is this some master plan to kill all humans on Earth?

Comment: Who says everything has to have a resonant frequency? If you strike a bell, it rings because it has an acoustic resonance. If you make a bell out of wet mud instead of metal, do you think it will still resonate?

Comment: Sticking to real science, different parts of the body resonate at different frequencies, for example arms at 100 MHz, head at 250 MHz, etc. The slight enhancement of the absorption of RF power at these frequencies is interesting from an RF safety point of view. Nothing in the body resonates at any kHz.

Comment: Thank you for the funny and informative comments! I'm still waiting for a "real expert" to answer the question but I provided an example answer with a circuit that I built and tested. Somehow I think something much simpler would be possible, but anyway, I'm not experienced with circuit design! @lucas92: The "master plan to kill all humans" is my other project...

Comment: ... By "real expert" I meant, someone like you guys, not me, who would provide an answer... I realize that I can only ping one person per comment, which is unfortunate since so many people commented, but ... @ThePhoton, any suggestions about the circuit I posted?

Comment: A human body in which pose and surrounded by what? Floating in the air, standing on the ground, standing on an isolating pad, sitting in a chair, or… ? A human can change its shape in a wide range and nearby objects can also alter EM fields greatly.

Comment: I think this is a good question, regardless of *your* opinion about the metaphysical aspects. One problem you will have with any frequency measurement from the body, is that *whatever* you use to connect with, would create it's own equivalent to an RC circuit. (Your skin is often modeled as an RC circuit.)